# jquery input focus goes away after setting

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 3.3.1; Bootstrap 4.1.1. My first page in this web app has username and password text boxes.  I want to put focus in the first text box so I do:

```
//
// put focus in the first non-hidden field on a page
$(":input:not(:hidden)").first().focus();
```

in my base javascript file.  I am using this in a different app and it works, or it seems to work.

In this app though I can load the page and see focus highlight the correct input field then it goes away.  I can see that my .js file is being loaded.  I can put a breakpoint on the line above and (in chrome) focus seems to be set but goes away before I can step over the line.  The line above is the next to last line in  the .js file; the last line is a `console.log()`.

I have also tried: `$(":input:not(:hidden)").eq(0).focus();` based on another SO question.

Comment: try with $("input:not(:hidden)")... // without the : at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the document has loaded before hand and use the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:not(:hidden)').first().focus();
});
```